# Remove extra "Publish Locations" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, publishing

I have old folder crud I can't figure out how to remove - extra "Publishing Folder Locations" and extra "Installation Folder URL"'s.  In the example below, I'd like to trim the five choices down to two, but can't find anything on how to do this.  File searches in the solution for "server03" turn up empty - is it encrypted somewhere?  Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, just found it - this has been vexing me for months.  There is a Myproj.csproj.user file that has this info with the different options delimited by a pipe char "|".  All I had to do was remove the options I didn't want.  I don't know why this isn't considered part of the project.